# React - Cannot render list item that is retrieved from API

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a react application that outputs a list of books (image, title, category, and description).
My search bar and booklist are sibling components and the search bar will pass data to the booklist.

when clicking the search button, only "Sample Category" shows up but not anything else. There is no problem accessing the API and the data is not null.

Here is a sample API output: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=lordoftherings

My code is the following:

// App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import BookList from './BookList';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      books: []
    };

    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  search(title) {
    const promise = Axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + title);
    promise.then((response) => {
        const books = response.data.items;
        this.setState({ books: books });
        console.log(this.state.books);
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar searchBooks = {this.search}/>
        <BookList booklist = {this.state.books}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

// Search Bar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { titleToSearch: 'harry potter' }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({ titleToSearch: e.target.value });
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="booksInput"
                    placeholder="Enter book title"
                    value={this.state.titleToSearch}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
                <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.searchBooks(this.state.titleToSearch)}>Search</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

// BookList

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BookList extends Component {

    render() {
        const books = this.props.booklist;
        return (
            <div className="table">
                {books.map((book) => {
                    console.log(book.id);
                    return (
                        <div className="box" key={book.id}>
                            <div className="img"><img src="assets/default-placeholder.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                            <div className="title">{book.title}</div>
                            <div className="category">Sample Category</div>
                            <div className="description">{book.description}</div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BookList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample code you provided, you're not actually dynamically outputting categories.
You've hard coded 'Sample category' in there.

```
book.category
```

...is not actually in the dataset.
There are categories which seem to be available under:

```
<div className="category">{book.volumeInfo.categories[0]}</div>
```

although you'll want to check if the array has length, and probably map or join each item in array to string.

just to be clear: the issue with your other fields is also that they're children of   "volumeInfo"